# How to clear ng-init value on button click event?

Tags: angularjs

Here is my code, I want to reset **items.total** model.
its not working

```
<div ng-init="items.total">
   <ul ng-repeat="x in Arr">
      <li ng-init = "items.total.carat = items.total.carat + x.Carat">{{x.Carat}}</li>
   </ul>
</div>
<label>{{items.total.carat}}</label>
<input type="button" ng-click="GetNewData()" value="FETCH">
----------------------------------------------
script :

$scope.GetNewData = function(){
   $scope.items = {};
   -- code --
};
```

Comment: Make $scope.items.total=''"; inside your function.

Comment: @Vivz  it will give error. items is undefined.

Comment: What about $scope.items={"total":""};?

Answer (score 1):

You can put multiple calling in `ng-click` like following

```
<input type="button" ng-click="GetNewData(); items.total = null;" value="FETCH">
```

Adding to this you can pass `items` in function and clear it right there

```
<input type="button" ng-click="GetNewData(items); items.total = null;" value="FETCH">
```

Other than this you can call only method and clear it in your controller after all the operation

Like

```
$scope.GetNewData = function(){
   /* do necessary operation */
   $scope.items = {}; //empty it out
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `ng-init` to total items in a list is an abuse of that directive:

> [The `ng-init`] directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses of `ngInit`, such as for aliasing special properties of `ngRepeat`, as seen in the demo below; and for injecting data via server side scripting. Besides these few cases, **you should use controllers** rather than `ngInit` to initialize values on a scope.
>
> [— AngularJS `ng-init` Directive Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)

Instead use a JavaScript function to total the value:

```
$scope.computeTotal = function() {
    $scope.items.total.caret = 0;
    for (let i=0; i<$scope.Arr.length; i++) {
       $scope.items.total.caret += $scope.Arr[i];
    };
};
```

AngularJS separates concerns into Model, View, and Controller. The template (or View) should only render the Model. The Controller should create and update the Model as needed. This [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) simplifies the development and maintenance of applications.